# SQL find and replace across table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to run `reg_exp_replace` on all the columns in my table. For one row, here's how it looks like -

```
UPDATE table 
   SET field = regexp_replace(field, 'foo', 'bar', 'g' )
```

Is there a way to do the same for all columns other than the obvious way of painfully listing out each and every column? i.e.

```
UPDATE table 
   SET field1 = regexp_replace(field1, 'foo', 'bar', 'g' )
   SET field2 = regexp_replace(field2, 'foo', 'bar', 'g' )
   SET field3 = regexp_replace(field3, 'foo', 'bar', 'g' )
```

I'm using Postgres, so Postgres-specific solutions are welcome.

Comment: You could use the data dictionary to write a query which writes your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function builds a query to replace `pattern` with `replacement` using `flags` in all text columns of table `table_name`.
The function returns text of the query. If `run` is `true` then the function executes the query.

```
create or replace function regexp_replace_in_table
    (table_name text, pattern text, replacement text, flags text, run boolean)
returns text language plpgsql
as $$
declare
    r record;
    q text;
begin
    q = format('update %s set ', table_name);
    for r in
        select attname
        from pg_attribute
        where attrelid = table_name::regclass
            and attnum > 0
            and not attisdropped
            and atttypid = 25   -- column is of text type
        order by attnum
    loop
        q = format($fmt$%s %s = regexp_replace(%s, '%s', '%s', '%s'),$fmt$, 
            q, r.attname, r.attname, pattern, replacement, flags);
    end loop;
    q = format('%s;', rtrim(q, ','));
    if run then
        execute q;
    end if;
    return q;
end $$;

select regexp_replace_in_table('my_table', 'foo', 'bar', 'g', false);
```